# How can I move a `std::vector` member variable to the caller of a method?

Tags: c++, c++11, move

Please consider the following piece of code

```
class A
{
public:
    A(std::size_t d)
        : m_v(d)

    std::vector<double> operator()() {
        return m_v;
    }

private:
    std::vector<double> m_v;
};
```

I want to *move* `m_v` to the caller of `operator()` instead of copying it. What do I need to do? Simply write `return std::move(m_v)` and change the return type to `std::vector<double>&&`?

Comment: Are you sure you want to suck the data out of `A` like that?

Comment: That would work, but it would be unusual that your `A` object is now storing a vector in an unknown state.  Do you really want to have *no expectations* regarding the state of `A::m_v`?

Comment: @juanchopanza Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: At least be kind to your co-workers and call your function `detach` or `release`

Comment: @DrewDormann `A` is a nested class which basically wraps some resources and will be destroyed after the call of `operator()`.

Comment: this is ugly but will do what you want

Comment: If you use an rvalue reference (`std::vector<double>&&`) as the return type, what happens to `m_v` will depend entirely on what happens to the return value, the whether or not an instance of `A` owns its vector becomes less predictable. If you use `std::vector<double>` instead, the behavior should be the same when passing into functions which take rvalue references, but the instance's vector will *always* be in a moved-from state after a call to `operator()` because it uses it to move-construct a temporary. Ultimately your choice depends on what you want from this function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to write `return std::move(m_v)`.

Comment: Without changing the return type?

Comment: @0xbadf00d  There is no need to change the return type. The corresponding returned object is a temporary object.